# OpenCV - how to form up a .avi from a list of .ppm files

Tags: c++, image, video, opencv

I have a library to convert `.oni` file(video format from kinect) to `.ppm` files corresponding to each frame of the recorded video.

Based on these `.ppm` files I want to build a `.avi` file.

Is there any opencv function for doing this?

Any suggestion would help.

Comment: You can use `imread`/`cvLoadImage` to load the images and then write them to a [`VideoWriter`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/highgui_reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html) / `cvCreateVideoWriter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use mencoder/ffmpeg to convert the pp to avi. [Here](http://electron.mit.edu/~gsteele/ffmpeg/) is a tutorial.